# Playing with Referer Header

Tags: web-application, web-browser, php, javascript

There are 2 sites:

```
http://www.site1.com
http://www.site2.com
```

`http://www.site1.com` contains link to `http://www.site2.com` as

```
<a href="http://www.site2.com/">link<a/>
```

When user clicks on link from `http://www.site1.com` browser sends Referer header to `http://www.site2.com`. Based on Referrer header `http://www.site2.com` makes some processes.

I wonder if I can fake/change (maybe with javascript, PHP, ...) Referer header or not send it at all?

Comment: I think there might be a way to block the referrer in modern html/js. I remember it being mentioned somewhere.

Comment: The classical solution is to use a intermediate redirector that masks the original source.

Comment: I currently have a bounty on a similar question ( https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/109954/54133 ): how can I set the referer policy for all the sites but one? So, I'm posting this comment here, in case someone know the answer…

Comment: When you say "...I can fake...", who is "I"? The person running site1? The user clicking the link? Someone else?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are **two situations** in which you would want to control the `Referer` header. By the way, `Referer` is a miss-spelling of the word "referrer".

If you want to control **your personal browser** not to pass the `Referer` to `site2.com`, you can do that with many browser extensions:

- For Firefox there is [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) (which I use and am happy with. I use the option "Forge- send the root of the site")
- Chrome has [Referer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en)

The other situation is where you are a **webmaster** and you want the **users of your site** (site1.com) not to send the `Referer` to other sites linked on your site. You can do that in multiple ways:

- Use SSL/TLS (https) on your site and a security feature of the browser is not to pass the `Referer`to HTTP links on your pages served up with SSL/TLS. However, if the links on your pages use HTTPS, then `Referer` will still be passed over unless explicitly turned off by other means described below.
- Use the HTML5 `rel="noreferrer"` attribute. It is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=noreferrer) by all major browsers.
- Use a Data URL ('data:') to hide the actual page the link is coming from: `<a href='data:text/html;charset=utf-8, <html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=&#39;http://site2.com/&#39;"></html>'>Link text</a>`.
- Hide the `Referer` by redirecting through an intermediate page. This type of redirection is often used to prevent potentially-malicious links from gaining information using the `Referer`, for example a session ID in the query string. Many large community websites use link redirection on external links to lessen the chance of an exploit that could be used to steal account information, as well as make it clear when a user is leaving a service, to lessen the chance of effective phishing.

Here is a simplistic redirection example in PHP:

```
<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
header( 'Refresh: 0; url=http://'.$url );
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Redirecting...</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://<?php echo $url; ?>">
 </head>
 <body>
 Attempting to redirect to <a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>">http://<?php echo $url; ?></a>.
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the "Use SSL/TLS" listing, can someone detail this? I've tested on a site with TLS 1.2, and by default, the Referrer is still getting passed around, both when taking an outside link, and navigating between pages.

Comment: The Referer is only removed when navigating from a HTTPS site to a HTTP site.

Comment: Wouldn't this PHP redirect example be susceptible to XSS?

Answer (score 11):

**As of 2015 this is how you prevent your website from sending the Referer header:**

Just add this to the head section of the web page:

```
 <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

This works **both for links and for Ajax requests** made by JavaScript code on the page.

Other valid `meta` options include:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url" />
<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" />
<meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin" />
```

• See if it works for your browser here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy

• See specs here: http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/referrer-policy/

**Note:** If you want to remove the referrer by using JavaScript only, I believe you could add the appropriate meta tag dynamically just before making the Ajax request. I have not tested this, however.

Also note that browsers now send the `Origin` header which includes domain and port, and, as far as I know, cannot be removed. If you use `<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />` the referrer will contain
similar information to the `Origin` header, which is already good from a privacy point of view, since it will hide the exact page the user is in.

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the referer header unless you control the calling client, e.g. the browser.

Browsers block modifying the referer, and server-side code can't inject headers into a request as there is no way to get the header from the server to the client, and make the client inject it into the referer header of it's next request.

That's assuming the browser doesn't have a particular vulnerability around header injection from JavaScript though.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent overview of the referral problem and its history can be found in ["Stripping referrer for fun and profit"](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/10/stripping-referrer-for-fun-and-profit.html).

The same article also contains links to:

1. [referer.us](https://referer.us/), an URL redirection service, which now redirects to [url.rw](https://url.rw/), but which  **neither should be trusted,**
2. A [browser-independent client-side script](https://webstersprodigy.net/2013/02/01/stripping-the-referer-in-a-cross-domain-post-request/), using the awesome `<iframe src=about:blank>` trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a python script (see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ for a great library, if the standard urllib looks complicated) but I think you would be able to spoof the referer using Tamper data / live http header plugin for firefox. Not sure tho, but have a look.
There is also other firefox addons the lets you manipulate the referer header. Just search for referer in the firefox addons.

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to build an HTTP Header.

You only need a terminal and some *swiss knife* like `netcat` (It's a tool that lets you do very basics things, like `cat` on network).

Someting like:

```
nc << eof www.site2.com 80
GET /somepath/somedest HTTP/1.0
Host: wwww.site2.com
Referer: wwww.site1.com

.
eof
```

Could be enough.

(Note: the dot `.` at the end is useless, but an empty line marks the end of header)

So the answer is **yes** it's possible to fake an HTTP Header.

***This was done on firefox 19.0***

For **hiding** the referer field, I've used an option in `squid` proxy server from some years ago, but I'm sure that there must exist some modules or extensions for a browser which would do the trick....

...A quick look in my firefox (v19.0) config let me see that there is an option: `network.http.sendRefererHeader`.

This option could be set to:

- `0` Never send the Referer header or set document.referrer.
- `1` Send the Referer header when clicking on a link, and set document.referrer for the following page.
- `2` *(Default)* Send the Referer header when clicking on a link or loading an image, and set document.referrer for the following page.